# Shift with condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame

```
                 dt_object     price  buy  
311684 2020-12-24 18:15:00  73.98250  NaN   
311685 2020-12-24 18:30:00       NaN  NaN   
311686 2020-12-24 18:45:00  73.98520  NaN   
311687 2020-12-24 19:00:00  74.16250 True   
311688 2020-12-24 19:15:00  74.06500  NaN   
311689 2020-12-24 19:30:00  74.01000  NaN   
311690 2020-12-24 19:45:00  74.12690  NaN  
311691 2020-12-24 20:00:00  74.04500  NaN   
311692 2020-12-24 20:15:00  74.05090  NaN   
311693 2020-12-24 20:30:00       NaN  NaN   
311694 2020-12-24 20:45:00  74.02670  NaN   
311695 2020-12-24 21:00:00  73.99356 True   
311696 2020-12-24 21:15:00  74.01461  NaN   
311697 2020-12-24 21:30:00  74.02120  NaN   
311698 2020-12-24 21:45:00  73.95500  NaN  
311699 2020-12-24 22:00:00  73.95800  NaN   
311700 2020-12-24 22:15:00  73.95900  NaN   
311701 2020-12-24 22:30:00  73.98760  NaN   
311702 2020-12-24 22:45:00  73.98100 True   
311703 2020-12-24 23:00:00  73.90500  NaN   
311704 2020-12-24 23:15:00  73.91300  NaN   
311705 2020-12-24 23:30:00       NaN  NaN   
311706 2020-12-24 23:45:00       NaN  NaN   
311707 2020-12-25 00:00:00  74.06600  NaN  
311708 2020-12-25 00:15:00  73.97810  NaN   
311709 2020-12-25 00:30:00  74.00020  NaN
311710 2020-12-25 00:45:00  73.81300  NaN
311711 2020-12-25 01:00:00  73.99950  NaN
```

In column **buy** you see where I buy stock. I want to sell it 3 rows below. But if column **price** is **NaN** in this row I want to sell on the next row with valid price.
So expected output is:

```
                 dt_object     price  buy  sell
311684 2020-12-24 18:15:00  73.98250  NaN   NaN
311685 2020-12-24 18:30:00       NaN  NaN   NaN
311686 2020-12-24 18:45:00  73.98520  NaN   NaN
311687 2020-12-24 19:00:00  74.16250 True   NaN
311688 2020-12-24 19:15:00  74.06500  NaN   NaN
311689 2020-12-24 19:30:00  74.01000  NaN   NaN
311690 2020-12-24 19:45:00  74.12690  NaN  True
311691 2020-12-24 20:00:00  74.04500  NaN   NaN
311692 2020-12-24 20:15:00  74.05090  NaN   NaN
311693 2020-12-24 20:30:00       NaN  NaN   NaN
311694 2020-12-24 20:45:00  74.02670  NaN   NaN
311695 2020-12-24 21:00:00  73.99356 True   NaN
311696 2020-12-24 21:15:00  74.01461  NaN   NaN
311697 2020-12-24 21:30:00  74.02120  NaN   NaN
311698 2020-12-24 21:45:00  73.95500  NaN  True
311699 2020-12-24 22:00:00  73.95800  NaN   NaN
311700 2020-12-24 22:15:00  73.95900  NaN   NaN
311701 2020-12-24 22:30:00  73.98760  NaN   NaN
311702 2020-12-24 22:45:00  73.98100 True   NaN
311703 2020-12-24 23:00:00  73.90500  NaN   NaN
311704 2020-12-24 23:15:00  73.91300  NaN   NaN
311705 2020-12-24 23:30:00       NaN  NaN   NaN
311706 2020-12-24 23:45:00       NaN  NaN   NaN
311707 2020-12-25 00:00:00  74.06600  NaN  True
311708 2020-12-25 00:15:00  73.97810  NaN   NaN
311709 2020-12-25 00:30:00  74.00020  NaN   NaN
311710 2020-12-25 00:45:00  73.81300  NaN   NaN
311711 2020-12-25 01:00:00  73.99950  NaN   NaN
```

How to fill **sell** column with pandas? I know about **shift** method. But it cannot be used here because I have **NaN** values in column **price**.

UPDATE
The first part of my question was answered perfectly by Stef. Let me ask you the second part.
I want to see sell price in row where I do buy action. It let me see in row both buy and sell prices.
Expected output:

```
                 dt_object     price  buy  sell   sell_price
311684 2020-12-24 18:15:00  73.98250  NaN   NaN          NaN
311685 2020-12-24 18:30:00       NaN  NaN   NaN          NaN
311686 2020-12-24 18:45:00  73.98520  NaN   NaN          NaN
311687 2020-12-24 19:00:00  74.16250 True   NaN     74.12690
311688 2020-12-24 19:15:00  74.06500  NaN   NaN          NaN
311689 2020-12-24 19:30:00  74.01000  NaN   NaN          NaN
311690 2020-12-24 19:45:00  74.12690  NaN  True          NaN
311691 2020-12-24 20:00:00  74.04500  NaN   NaN          NaN
311692 2020-12-24 20:15:00  74.05090  NaN   NaN          NaN
311693 2020-12-24 20:30:00       NaN  NaN   NaN          NaN
311694 2020-12-24 20:45:00  74.02670  NaN   NaN          NaN
311695 2020-12-24 21:00:00  73.99356 True   NaN     73.95500  
311696 2020-12-24 21:15:00  74.01461  NaN   NaN          NaN
311697 2020-12-24 21:30:00  74.02120  NaN   NaN          NaN
311698 2020-12-24 21:45:00  73.95500  NaN  True          NaN
311699 2020-12-24 22:00:00  73.95800  NaN   NaN          NaN
311700 2020-12-24 22:15:00  73.95900  NaN   NaN          NaN
311701 2020-12-24 22:30:00  73.98760  NaN   NaN          NaN
311702 2020-12-24 22:45:00  73.98100 True   NaN     74.06600
311703 2020-12-24 23:00:00  73.90500  NaN   NaN          NaN
311704 2020-12-24 23:15:00  73.91300  NaN   NaN          NaN
311705 2020-12-24 23:30:00       NaN  NaN   NaN          NaN
311706 2020-12-24 23:45:00       NaN  NaN   NaN          NaN
311707 2020-12-25 00:00:00  74.06600  NaN  True          NaN
311708 2020-12-25 00:15:00  73.97810  NaN   NaN          NaN
311709 2020-12-25 00:30:00  74.00020  NaN   NaN          NaN
311710 2020-12-25 00:45:00  73.81300  NaN   NaN          NaN
311711 2020-12-25 01:00:00  73.99950  NaN   NaN          NaN
```

**sell_price** gets price from row where I do sell action (True value in **sell** column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shift the rows where there is a price. When assigning it as a new column `sell` pandas will automatically align it at the index.

```
df['sell'] = df[df.price.notna()].buy.shift(3)
```

Or even better `df.loc[df.price.notna(), 'buy'].shift(3)` as per @ansev's comment below.

---

**Update**: to add the sell price from the sell row we can use the same approach, just the other way round:

```
df['sell_price'] = df.loc[df.price.notna(), 'price'].shift(-3).loc[df.buy.fillna(False)]
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.price.notna(), 'buy'].shift(3)` : )

Comment: @ansev oh, yes, of course - thanks, I'll edit it

Comment: Thanks, dear friend! I added a new comment at the bottom. Take a look at it please.